# How to get the RAW Body using serverless functions?

Tags: node.js, serverless, vercel

I am migrating from Express to serverless functions on Zeit Now.

The Stripe [webhook docs](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures) asks for a raw body request, When using Express I could get it via bodyParser, but how does it work on serverless functions? How can I receive the body in a string format in order to validate the stripe signature?

The support team redirected me to this [documentation link](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/supported-languages/#node.js-helpers), I'm confused, as I understand, I have to pass `text/plain` into the request header, but I don't have control over it since Stripe is the one sending the webhook.

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    let sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
    let rawBody = req.body;
    let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET);
    ...
}
```

In my function, I'm receiving `req.body` as an object, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code snippet worked for me (modified from this [source](https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/how-to-get-raw-body-using-serverless-functions~5c0c71de-a3ec-42a9-a9b0-24a575e59006?m=MTU3ODkzMTQ3MTAwNg==)):

```js
const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;

export default async (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;
  let bodyChunks = [];

  req
    .on('data', chunk => bodyChunks.push(chunk))
    .on('end', async () => {
      const rawBody = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks).toString('utf8');

      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
      } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      }

      // Handle event here
      ...

      // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
      res.json({ received: true });
    });
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```